# Why is my C++11 program working on Linux and Mac only but showing error on Windows?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have made a simple program in C++11 that takes text from one `.txt` file (e.g. `input.txt`) and inserts it into another `.txt` file (e.g. `output.txt`) with the row numbers printed before the text.

Here is how the output looks like:

[image]

The problem is that the program works only on Mac and Linux. On Windows, it displays the following error:

> Output file output.txt not found

EDIT: Here's the screenshot of the error:

[image]

The program is executed in the terminal where you enter the paths to both input and output files.

Can someone please help me understand why this code runs smoothly on one system but not on another?

My code is below:

```cpp
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    std::ifstream in(argv[1]); 
    std::ofstream out(argv[2]); 
    int p=1, i=1;
    for (char b; in.get(b);) {
        if (i==1){
           out<<p<<" ";
           i=0;}
    out<<b;
    if(b=='\n') { 
        i=1;
        ++p;}}

    out.close();
    in.close(); 
}
```

Comment: What are you using for your input and output paths?

Comment: The error is hard to understand, can you post a screenshot of that?

Comment: Your identation makes it hard to read your code and to see where loops and blocks start and end. Regarding your question: I guess your output path does not exist.

Comment: @john I've edited the question, added a screenshot. For paths I was entering location of the files into the terminal and it worked on my Mac. However, when other people tested the program on Windows and they entered paths where they have these files stored it showed an error.

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to match your output, please post a [mre]. The outputs are better as text rather than screenshots

Comment: I've never seen error messages like that on Windows, and they're not produced by the code above.

Comment: @WernerHenze the output.txt exists in that location as you enter the path to it. It just shows that it doesn't exists on Windows machines.
P.S. Thanks for the comment on my indentation, I will be working on improving it.

Comment: This is not an error message from your program but from some framework that runs your program!? Then you should check the framework.

Comment: If the output file doesn't exist, it will be created. Vote to close.

Comment: I certainly can't see anything wrong with the code. I think the problem is somewhere else. Something like the framework that Werner Henze suggested.

Comment: @WernerHenze turns out our lecturer used his own program to run our code, that is where error was from. I asked to friend run this code in his Windows terminal, there was no error, BUT the output.txt file was just empty

Comment: @john I've just replied to Werner Henze that it was indeed some framework problem. However, when you run it simply in Windows terminal it still gives no output as on Mac

Comment: Likeliest reason for that is that the input file does not exist. At least not in the location that the program is looking for it. **Always** check that file opens succeed and take action if they don't.

Comment: Basically this isn't a code problem (apart from the fact that it could do a bit more error checking). It's an environment problem.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the answers! Looks like it's indeed an environment problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is you are running your application as:
application.exe input.txt output.txt , make sure they exist and in the same location as application is

Check names of file carefully

Comment: The question concerns the output file. Output files don't have to exist before you run a program.